# How to set the "Not After" of validity period when I create the X.509 certificate using makecert.exe

Tags: certificate, x509, digital-certificate, makecert

I create a X.509 certificate using makecert.exe. And then I find the validity period of the certificate is from 2016/11/1 to 2040/01/01.
How to set the end of the validity period?

Comment: Beware that makecert is deprecated and is not recommended for use anymore. It is outdated and uses weak cryptography. To create self-signed certificates, use the New-SelfSignedCertificate.PowerShell cmdlet or CertEnroll COM interfaces.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it after I finish this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find MakeCert.exe includes a basic options can solve this problem. For example：

> makecert -e 12/31/2080

-e DateEnd
type in mm/dd/yyyy
Date when the validity period ends. The default is the year 2039.